# Resolve promises sequentially resulting in error

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, promise, sequence

I have been trying to loop through an array of IDs and passing them into a function (this.handleTransfer) that calls an API. I want the next iteration to only kick in only when a response is received from the previous iteration.
I decided to google how to use promises to do this.
But when I implemented what I got online, the error below occurs after the first iteration:

```
TypeError: e(...).then is not a function.
```

The source is the error was this block of code

```
return e().then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(t))
```

My code is below:

```
const promiseSerial = funcs =>
        funcs.reduce((promise, func) =>
          promise.then(result => func().then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(result))),
          Promise.resolve([]))

        const payments = this.payIDArray;

        const funcs = payments.map(payment => () => this.handleTransfer(payment))

        promiseSerial(funcs)
        .then(console.log.bind(console))
        .catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

I'm using the VueJS framework.

Comment: `this.handleTransfer(payment)` does not return a promise?

Comment: what about async await? It would be much easier to build your sequence

Comment: And `.then(res => [...result, res])` is way more readable then that function binding

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for pointing that out. Apparently this.handleTransfer(payment) was returning any promise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the sample code you posted, I made some assumptions.

- First, from your use of `... promise.then(result => func().then ...`
  I made the assumption that `this.handleTransfer(payment)` returns a
  function, and that function returns a promise.
- Second, from your use
  of concatenation, I'm assuming the data your API call sends back is an
  array.

The `promiseSerial` implementation below returns a promise chain that resolves to a concatenation of all the arrays returned by the `this.handleTransfer(payments)` calls while preserving the sequence of the calls.

```
const promiseSerial = (funcs) => funcs.reduce((resultPromise, apiPromise) => {
    return resultPromise.then((concatenatedAPIResponses) => {
        const apiCallPromise = apiPromise(); //because this.handleTransfer(payment) returns a function  
        //const apiCallPromise = apiPromise; if this.handleTransfer(payment) returns a promise instead of a function

        return apiCallPromise.then((apiCallResponse) => {
            concatenatedAPIResponses = concatenatedAPIResponses.concat(apiCallResponse)
            return concatenatedAPIResponses
        })
    })
}, Promise.resolve([]))
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNoaKG)

Comment: I'm accepting this because you gave me another method to go about solving my problem. Thanks mate..